# Is there some sort of correspondence between groups and partitions of a set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, set-partition

Every group action on a set $S$ partitions the set into orbits.  Conversely, for every partition of $S$ is there a group action such that the set of orbits of the group action equals the partition?

My attempt.  Let $P = \{S_1,\dots, S_k\}$  be a partition of a finite set $S$ of order $n$.  Then there are elements of $G = Perm(S)$, the set of permutations of $S$, that leave each subset fixed, i.e. $g\in G$ such that $g\cdot S_i = \{gs : s\in S_i\} = S_i, \forall i$.  Think of the permutations that fix all of $S$ except permutes $S_i$ possibly in some nontrivial way.  If $g, h$ are such elements then $gS_i = S_i, \forall i$, so $g^{-1} S_i = S_i$, the action also being an action on the subsets.  Similarly $g\cdot h S_i = g S_i = S_i$.  Thus, the set of all $P$-stabilizing elements is a subgroup of $G$.

Groups are known in correspondence with subgroups of $G$.  Please comment.

Motivation: is there a group-theoretical way to count partitions of a set of size $n$?  So that maybe it can help prove formulas about the latter.

According to m_l in a comment, there's no application here to counting partitions here that doesn't lead to having to count the partitions the known ways.

I was thinking, we haven't considered yet, at least I haven't, the set of partitions of $S$ itself, call it $P(S)$, and the group $G = Perm(S)$ acting on it.  The nice thing about $G = Perm(S)$ is that every finite group is isomorphic to a subgroup of it.  So if $H \leqslant G$, and $H'$ is the group presented in some other way, then almost anything we say about $H$ can be applied to $H'$ regarding group actions on $S$ or $P(S)$.  Hopefully, so let's keep that in the back of our minds.  In other words, every partition corresponds to a partition of the set of subgroups of $G$.  But we should say more about it than that.  I'm moving off track here, so continuing on...

Define the action of $G$ on $P(S), $ to be $g \cdot P = \cup_{i=|P|} \{ g\cdot S_i \}$, where $g\cdot S_i$ is the element $g$ acting on the block $S_i$ suing simple coset multpilcation.  Relatedly there's an obvious way to make $G$ act on the set of all subsets of $S$.

Anyway.  As you can tell the action on $P(S)$ defines a group action.  Proof:
The identity permutation obviously fixes a partition.  And $g(h P) = g\cdot\cup_{i=1..|P|} \{ h\cdot S_i \}$.  Note that since $g$ acts on the set of subsets of $S$, $g(hP) = (gh)P. \ $  The rest of the proof is left to the reader.

Let's switch notation a bit.  $P\in P(S)$ will now be called $p$, and $P(S)$ will be called $P$.

An orbit is simply $O_p = G\cdot p \subset P(S)$.  We have the *class equation*

$|P(S)| = \sum_{orbits} |O_p|$

Burnside's Lemma:

*# orbits* $ = 1/|G| \sum_{g\in G}|P^g|, \ $ where $P^g$ is the set of all partitions fixed by $g$.

and the index counting formula

$|G| = |H_p||O_p| = |H_p|[G:H_p], \ $ where $H_p = Stab(p)$ is the stabilizer of the partition $p$.

Comment: You have stumbled upon the subgroup $\Sigma_{\lambda_1} \times \cdots \times \Sigma_{\lambda_k}$ of $\Sigma_n$, where $(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k)$ is the partition of $n$.

Comment: Do you have a name for that?  Can't google that

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is "block".  If the entire symmetric group acts on the $n$-element set $S$, then the subgroup that I mentioned is the stabilizer of the blocks (*i.e.* parts of the partition).  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(permutation_group_theory)

Comment: Blocks are usually considered for transitive actions and blocks can be mapped to one another by an action! But yes, the stabiliser of $P$ as a list in the symmetric group on $S$ is exactly the direct product of the symmetric groups on the $S_i$.

Comment: Is there a way to count partitions of $S$ using this?

Comment: Answers welcome.  My motivation was another problem showing $p(n)^2 \lt p(n^2 + 2n)$ or something similar where $p$ is the number of partitions of a set of size $n$.  I was wondering if there is a group-theoretical way to show that.  Thanks for the complement.

Comment: I don't see a way to count partitions using this correspondence which does not involve counting partitions. The obvious approach would be counting the direct products $S_{\lambda_1} \times \ldots \times S_{\lambda_k}$, but this is exactly the same as counting partitions themselves.

Note also the somewhat subtle difference between the stabiliser of $P$ and the subgroup which stabilises each $S_i$ (the stabiliser of $P$ may still permute $S_i, S_j$ as blocks if $|S_i| = |S_j|$).

Comment: One more thing that comes to mind is the representation theory of the symmetric group. The number of partitions of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ equals the number of irreducible representations of $S_n$.

Comment: These subgroups (of finite symmetric groups at least) are called Young subgroups. And they are not suited to count partitions; every Young subgroup corresponds to a partition, but that just amounts to a rather complicated way of describing partitions. Group theoretic methods usually stick to a single group; within the symmetric group Young subgroup are just a small sub-class of all subgroups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S$ be a set (not necessarily finite) and $\mathcal{P}=\{P_i\}_{i\in I}$ some partition of $S$. Define

$$G_i:=\{f:P_i\to P_i\ |\ f\mbox{ is invertible}\}$$

With standard function composition $G_i$ is a group. If $P_i$ is finite then it is the standard symmetric group $S_{|P_i|}$. It acts on $P_i$ via $(f, x)\mapsto f(x)$. You can easily check that $P_i$ is transitive (i.e. it has only one orbit) under this action.

Now put $G:=\prod G_i$ and define the action

$$\big((f_i), x)\big)\mapsto f_j(x)\mbox{ if }x\in P_j$$

You can easily check that $S/G=\mathcal{P}$.

**Side note:** If we assume the Axiom of Choice or assume that each $P_i$ is at most countable then we can make $G$ smaller. Just define $G_i:=P_i$ with any group structure and put again $G:=\prod G_i$. Note that the statement "any set can be turned into a group" is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice. However it is true for at most countable sets independent on the Axiom of Choice.

**Side note2:** The $G$ can be refined even more if each $P_i$ is finite and $I$ is finite. Define $G:=\mathbb{Z}_n$ where $n=lcm(|P_i|)$ (least common multiple). Since $P_i$ is equinumerous with $G/H$ for some $H$ then it can be easily equipped with transitive action. That's probably the smallest $G$ we can get for finite case.

**Side note3:**

> The nice thing about $G=Perm(S)$ is that every finite group is isomorphic to a subgroup of it.

No. That's not a nice thing. It actually is an epicly horrible thing, because it means that proving anything about $G$ is at least as hard as proving anything about any other group.

Comment: "That's probably the smallest $G$ we can get for finite case." Not by far -- a _cyclic group_ of order $|P_i|$ will suffice.

Comment: @HenningMakholm $P_i$ may differ in size so $G$ of order $|P_i|$ doesn't even make sense. And since every transitive set is of size that divides $|G|$ then I dont think that we can get better then lcm over $|P_i|$.

Comment: x @freakish: Your $G_i$ has order $|P_i|!$ where $|P_i|$ would be enough. Multiplying those $G_i$s together afterwards is not going to help that.

Comment: @HenningMakholm what? As Ive written clearly $P_i$ might be infinite, $|P_i|!$ just doesn't make sense. Also ive written in a side notes how $G_i$ and $G$ can be reduced in finite case. I dont get your comments.

Comment: x @freakish: What you clearly wrote was: "That's probably the smallest G we can get **for finite case**." This is a direct quote -- I copied and pasted, didn't even type anything myself except to highlight "for the finite case".. This thing, which you have clearly written, is false -- the construction you're describing DOES NOT give the smallest group when $P_i$ is finite. The fact that $P_i$ might _also_ be infinite does not make your wrong statement about what happens when $P_i$ IS finite stop being wrong. I don/t get you insistence that you did not wrote what you did

Comment: @HenningMakholm i see now. That comment was misplaced, was supposed to be on remark2. I dont know why it happened earlier. That's why it was confusing for me. You are obviously right, ive updated the answer.