# Imagining a partition of a group as a group action.

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Every group action on a group $G$ induces a partition of $G$, but can we imagine any partition of $G$ as a group action?

Comment: Define "partition of a group". Do you mean an equivalence relation?

Comment: @DonAntonio: Partition of  á set and equivalence relation are 1-to-1.

Comment: @Wuestenfux That I know. I am asking to check whether the OP knows.

Comment: [Duplicate.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/506700/104041)